# Bayesian inference on a summary statistic

Tags: bayesian

I'm trying to set up a problem I'm working on to weight the inferences by number of observations, and from my very rudimentary understanding I think this sounds like it'd be appropriate to use a Bayesian inference framework.

The challenge is this. I'm trying to make inferences on the *sum* of all observations for a given sample. When we have more observations, we have a higher sum, but we also have more confidence that the sum represents the actual underlying 'Truth'. The real problem is that when we only have a small number of observations, the sum shouldn't really change our priors a whole lot because the observations we get are likely biased. But I don't how I'd set this up in a Bayesian context.

Originally, I was thinking I would use an MCMC chain, where the inferred parameters are the two shape parameters from a beta distribution (the sum will only vary from 0 to 1). But then when I was writing it out I realized that when I'm evaluating the likelihood it still only seems like I have one data point (the sum) for each sample, where I actually used different numbers of observations within each sample.

Any ideas are welcome!

PS: I'm not sure what the best title for this question would even be, which is partly the issue, I don't know what to google!

Comment: If you observe a sum $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ with the $X_i$'s iid $f_\theta(x)$, then $S_n$ has a density $g_{n,\theta}(s)$ for which a posterior can be derived.

Comment: Do you know where I could read more about this? I don't fully understand your comment.

Comment: No reading suggestion: this is simply a remark that Bayesian analysis uses the sampling distribution of the observables. Hence if $S_n$ is the only observable, the posterior distribution of $\theta$ should involve the sampling distribution of $S_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is unclear as making inference *on* a sum of observations$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$is meaningless since $S_n$ is *observed*. If the problem is to make inference on a parameter $\theta$ driving the law of the observations *given* $S_n$, i.e., assuming *only* $S_n$ is observed, said inference must rely on the likelihood $\ell_n(\theta|s_n)$ of the observation, namely $S_n$. There is nothing specifically Bayesian in the problem, but the posterior distribution on $\theta$ would then be$$\pi(\theta|S_n=s_n) \propto \pi(\theta) \times \ell_n(\theta|s_n)$$